# Probability of 2 appear before 3 or 5?

Tags: probability, dice

> Independent trial consisting of rolling a fair die perform. What is the probability of $2$ appear before $3$ or $5$??

Well, different explanation of the same question is available on some sites......But I could not figure out what's been asking for? And is there only one trial of rolling?

Comment: the question is far to be clear, so it cannot be uniquely interpreted. The probability, as you said, depends on the number of trials. If this number is not specified then it is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are repeatedly rolling a die until one of $2$, $3$, or $5$ appears. If it is a $2$ we have won. The probability that this is the case is ${1\over3}$, by symmetry.

Comment: This is easy to understand. Thanks for ur time.