# Probability of getting 2 or 4 before 3 or 6

Tags: probability

A fair dice is rolled over and over. What is the probability of getting $2$ or $4$ before getting $3$ or $6$ ?

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585202/probability-of-2-appear-before-3-or-5) answer, it is 1/2. As there is a probability of $\frac{1}{3} $ of $2$ or $4$ appears before $3$ or $6$ . Out of the total options of them both appearing which should be $$ \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{2} $$

Is it the correct way to solve?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "As there is a probability of  $\frac13$ of 2 / 4 appears before 3/ 6 ". Why would this be true?

Comment: @5xum the probabiliy of 2 appears before 3 should be 1/6 right?

Comment: Why would that be the case?

Comment: because of the answer in the linked question here.

Comment: The linked question has non sixths anywhere. Think of it this way: what is the probability that $3$ appears before $2$? is it also $\frac16$?

Comment: Yes. the probability of any number to appear before any other number is 1/6.

Comment: Yes, it works, we repeat the rolling till we get one of the 2,4,3,6... Note that one should mention that 1,5 cannot appear infinitely many times with positive probability

Comment: @bm1125 So... $2$ appears before $3$ in one sixth of the cases, and $3$ appears before $2$ in the other sixth of the cases... and what happens in the rest (two thirds) of the cases?

Comment: @5xum both do not appear at all??

Comment: @bm1125 But the dice is rolled over and over... Are you saying that there is a $\frac23$ chance that a fair dice never rolls either a $2$ or a $3$?

Comment: @5xum well that's I haven't thought about it this way... I don't know I guess.. maybe there's also the chance of only one of them appearing??

Comment: @bm1125 The probability of any number **never** appearing is $0$. The probability of one number appearing ahead of any other number, by symmetry, must be $\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore any roll that produces a 1 or a 5 since they have no bearing on which of the numbers 2, 3, 4, 6 appears first.  Each of these four numbers is equally likely to appear first among those four.  Since two of the four are a 2 or 4, the probability that a 2 or 4 appears before a 3 or 6 is 
$$\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $W=\frac13$ be the probability of a win (3 or 6), similarly for $L$ as a 2 or 4 and again for $D$ a 1 or 5.

Then the probability of a loss is the sum given by $L+DL+D^2L+\dots$, which is:

$$\frac13+\frac13\frac13+\frac13^2\frac13+\dots$$
$$=\frac13\left(\dfrac1{1-\frac13}\right)$$
$$=\frac12$$